# How to generate dynamic Github Actions run-name based on input variables?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm trying to generate a dynamic Github Actions **run-name** based on the input variables I receive. Specifically, I have two input variables: **required_version (required: true)** and **optional_instance_type (required: false)**.

Here's what I want to achieve:

If the **required_version** input is provided, I want the **run-name** to be in the following format:

```
run-name: "[${{ inputs.required_version }}]-[${{ inputs.optional_instance_type }}]"
```

If the **required_version** input is provided but **Not** **optional_instance_type**, I want the **run-name** to be in the following format:

```
run-name: "[${{ inputs.required_version}}]"
```

My Github Action code:

```
name: GitHub Action Workflow Runner Name

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      required_version:
        description: '(Required) Version'
        default: 'latest'
        required: true
        type: string
      optional_instance_type:
        description: '(Optional) instance type'
        required: false
        type: string

run-name: "[${{ inputs.required_version }}]-[${{ inputs.optional_instance_type }}]"

jobs:
  ...
```

Comment: You might be looking for an "if-then-else" expression like `${{ <expr-condition> && <true> || <false> }}`. I was able to make it working without combining `required_version` and `optional_instance_type`, but I don't know how to concatenate them. One think that worked is: `run-name: ${{ inputs.optional_instance_type != 0 && inputs.optional_instance_type || inputs.required_version }}` (if `optional_instance_type` is given, return it; else return required_version). I hope you can start with that.

Comment: By the way, you said "If the optional_instance_type input is provided but not the required_version" ... Impossible with your workflow, because you set required_version as required, hence must be provided. Maybe you meant the inverse?